# Missing $ inserted. <inserted text>

Tags: urls

I am getting the following error in LaTeX:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.172 ..._relations/jan-june97/bridges_2-18.html.}
```

I am using `\usepackage{url}` so not sure why the error. Below is the code from Line 172:

```
Her walk to school inspired the 1964 Norman Rockwell painting that he titled, 
"The Problem We Live With." This is a painting of a small black girl, escorted 
by four federal marshals, walking to school beside a wall bearing a scrawled 
racial slur and the letters KKK. Harvard psychiatry Professor Robert Coles 
witnessed the scene in New Orleans. Professor Coles has written a children's 
book about Rudy Bridges' experiences called "The Story of Ruby." In the book, 
Coles reminds children of the heroism of Bridges' action, by showing her facing 
an empty classroom because agry parents kept their children home and all but one 
teacher refused to teach a black child."\footnote{Excerpted from Online 
NewsHour:A Conservation with Ruby Bridges Hall-February 18, 1987,page 
1-https://www.pbs.org/newshour/bb/race_relations/jan-june97/bridges_2-18.html.}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Wrap the url in the `\url` command, how else would it know where the url is

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap the url in the \url command"?

Comment: `\url{url} `, the url package do have a manual, all latex packages do

Comment: Not that you may need `\protect\url` because it is inside a footnote

Comment: Unrelated: note that we do not use `"` for citation marks in latex. Do have a look at the csquotes package for a nice way of doing proper citation marks

Comment: Thank you very much! I put the url inside \url{url} and it worked! You are a GENIUS! Thank you Mico for revising the format of my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to load the `url` package. URL strings in the body of the document need to be encased in `\url` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl} % 'extended url'
\setlength\textheight{5.5cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
Her walk to school inspired the 1964 Norman Rockwell painting that he titled, 
``The Problem We Live With.'' This is a painting of a small black girl, escorted 
by four federal marshals, walking to school beside a wall bearing a scrawled 
racial slur and the letters KKK\@. Harvard psychiatry Professor Robert Coles 
witnessed the scene in New Orleans. Professor Coles has written a children's 
book about Rudy Bridges' experiences called ``The Story of Ruby.'' In the book, 
Coles reminds children of the heroism of Bridges' action, by showing her facing 
an empty classroom because agry parents kept their children home and all but one 
teacher refused to teach a black child.\footnote{Excerpted from Online NewsHour: 
A Conservation with Ruby Bridges Hall---February 18, 1987, page~1---%
\url{https://www.pbs.org/newshour/bb/race_relations/jan-june97/bridges_2-18.html}.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico, you and dalief are correct. I commented earlier. Thank you.

Comment: Mico, I have another question. Can you tell me why the quotation marks before the book title, The Problem We Live With is backwards when the PDF is generated? In fact, in the PDF file, ALL of the beginning quotations marks are backwards. Where can I find the LaTex manual? I downloaded LaTex from www.latex-project.org.

Comment: Why do you have a swirly between 'page' and '1' and why is there a '%' in front of \url{https://  . . .}?

Comment: @user219671 - About the appearance of the typographic opening single and double quotation marks: Their shapes are determined mainly by national customs. See the user guide of the [csquotes](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) package for more information.

Comment: @user219671 - In TeX and LaTeX, the `~` ("tilde", or "swirly", as you put it) character creates an unbreakable space; in fine typography, it's considered to be poor form to allow a line break between the word "page" and the page number. (It turns out not to matter in the sentence at hand. It's just a (good!) habit to insert `~` characters pro-actively.) The `%` ("percent") character is the comment character in TeX and LaTeX. Here, its presence prevents a space from being inserted between the em-space character and the start of the URL string.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.